# Spring circular dependency issue root cause

Tags: spring

I am having circular dependency in my application. I did not get any circular dependency issue while server startup on my local setup or other 3 setups I was working on.

But, I was getting circular dependency error on server startup on production environment.
Below was the error :
Error creating bean with name 'someBean': Bean with name 'someBean' has been injected into other beans [someOtherBean] in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped. This means that said other beans do not use the final version of the bean. This is often the result of over-eager type matching - consider using 'getBeanNamesOfType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for example.
when I added default-lazy-init = "true" in my application_context.xml file, error got resolved.

My question is, how come I wasn't getting any such error on my local or other setup even though I wasn't having default-lazy-init = "true" in my application_context.xml file. I came to know that the problem can be solved in several ways. But I would like to know the root cause of how spring differs in bean creation from one system to another. Or is it specific to OS or Tomcat server.

Comment: What was different about the system that didn't work?

Comment: There was no difference between ours and other system.

Comment: Any update on it, regarding the root case?